# JavaScript array.sort doesn't work on Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, javascript-objects

For some reason I can't sort my Array of Objects using Sort Function:

```
FullHistory.sort(function(a, b){
return a.Date.localeCompare(b.Date);
});
```

When I use console.log() - It returns: -1/0/1, but the Array's Order is not changing at all

[image: Evidence]

The rest of my Code:

```
let FullHistory = [];

    CurrentTitle = $(data).find(".normal_header").text().replace(" Episode Details", "");
    
    $($(data).find('.spaceit_pad').get().reverse()).each(function () {
        FullHistory.push({ Title: CurrentTitle, Ep: $(this).text().replace("Ep ", "").split(',')[0], Date: $(this).append(":00").text().replace("Ep ", "").replace("watched", "").replace(" Remove", "").split(",")[1].replace("on ", "").replace("at ", "").replace("  ", "") });
    });
```

I tried: changing let to var, using if statements in Sort Function, changing types, using Lodash Lib.

Comment: Please provide data as text, not as an image if text. That image, though, shows the data sorted by the Date field…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Date` properties will be sorted as strings -- that is what `localeCompare` does. It doesn't look at those strings as representing dates. Since the date format used is not ISO, the lexical order of those strings does match the order you would expect for the *dates*.

So convert the strings to numerical epochs:

```js
let FullHistory = [
    {Title: "Grand Blue", Ep: "1", Date: "02/19/2020 23:36:00" },
    {Title: "Darling in the FranXX", Ep: "1", Date: "03/04/2019 23:44:00" },
];

FullHistory.sort(function(a, b){
    return Date.parse(a.Date) - Date.parse(b.Date);
});

console.log(FullHistory);
```

Comment: I tried Date.parse and new Date - didn't help

Comment: If you provide your array in your question as *text* (not as screenshot), I'll add a runnable snippet with that data as input. Added one with 2 lines of data.

Comment: Now I'm really confused... Tried it once again, and now it works...
I've spent few hours, and in the end - one of my earliest solutions now started to work.
I'm literally speechless...
Thank You for the help!